# Two diodes in parallel for over-voltage protection

Tags: power-supply, diodes, high-voltage

I've got a power supply circuit that needs the input to be protected against some pretty big voltage spikes.  To do this, I need a really beefy clamping diode (D1) that will handle the voltage and current associated with those spikes.  I also have a second diode in parallel with less current/voltage handling capability, but with a higher breakdown voltage (D2).  My thought was that the secondary diode might react faster, but the primary diode would do the real voltage clamping.  The circuit below is a simplified version (not including additional bias components).

[image: Simplified Circuit]

My hope is that the two diodes will provide the response as shown below.  Is this a bad idea?  Any cautions or warnings for this type of implementation?

[image: Input Voltage Graphs]

Comment: I've seen <http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/6151/1571>, but it is not the same as what I'm asking. These are two different diodes and this parallel configuration is not for current handling capacity

Comment: I think it's better to use a Varistor instead of diodes.

Comment: Please post schematic of what you're trying to do.  Where do you plan for the energy to be dissipated?  Are these zeners?

Comment: Might this be a job for a MOV?  Hard to advise w/o a schematic to show just where this clamping is to be done.

Comment: It is hard to make suggestions without more of a few numbers to help understand the problem. "beefy", "pretty big spikes", mean very different things to a digital designer used to 5V or less at _fairly_ low amperage ( < 20A), than to a neon sign power supply designer, or an automotive _safe_ design.

Comment: Also is this for the input or for feedback protection on the output?

Comment: To summarize @mctylr: **numbers/context please.**

Comment: @mctylr - This is more of a conceptual question, and as such I don't really want part numbers, just want to know if the theory is correct

Answer (score 8):

It won't work -- if you put 2 diodes in parallel, I can't easily say how they will share current in the forward (conducting) direction, but in blocking, the LOWEST breakdown one will breakdown. The 2nd is useless.

You might put 2 in series, but this has its own problems (they don't split the applied V equally). Best to get a single component rated for what you want to do.

Comment: If the two have the same breakdown rating, they will likely share the current pretty well.  This is because there is some equivalent series resistance: the I/V characteristic is not completely vertical.

Comment: A single component won't do what I want to do as the turn on time for high energy handling parts is slower compared to that of lower energy handling parts.  That is why I'm attempting to split the work between the two and gain both responsiveness and current handling.

Answer (score 1):

Two 5KP22CA (5 kW, 22 V TVS) in parallel can clamp an SAE J1455 load dump (unloaded 100 V peak, 0.4 Ω impedance, 0.4 s fall-time if I recall correctly) to <30 V.

So long as your duty cycle is fairly low or the diodes thermally coupled, you can parallel TVS fairly well.  They are far from perfect Zeners as their standoff/breakdown/max voltage range is quite broad so one robbing all the surge from the other is unlikely.

Comment: are you sure that paralleling TVS is OK ? i am thinking since manufacturing is not perfect , one of them will start conducting before the other ...

Comment: I would have the same thoughts: One diode takes it (current) all ...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to research Gas Discharge Tube Arrestors.  These usually have higher current ratings than the equivalent TVS diodes.

I would replace the higher breakdown voltage diode with a GDT.  The TVS diode would start conducting for the small spikes and the GDT would suppress the large spikes.

Comment: I thought about that.  Once the GDT breaks down it becomes a short.  Under what conditions will that short become an open circuit again?

Comment: @JoelB, by memory, you need a power off event and a cooldown for it to turn off.

Comment: When the surge is over. However, I wonder if the GDT will even reach ignition voltage when the TVS diode is already conducting?

Comment: @Kortuk - That's what I remembered too, but I can't find it in writing anywhere, can you?

Comment: Looks like it will reset at 10 to 35V, depending on stuff.  -  http://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/product_catalogs/littelfuse_gdt_catalog.pdf.pdf  -  https://en.tdk.eu/download/174146/5dda6a276e51515ffdf5a9efb103de29/surge-arresters-pp.pdf  -  
https://www.digikey.com/-/media/Images/Product%20Highlights/B/Bourns%20Inc/Circuit%20Protection/Bourns-First-Principles-Gas-Discharge-Tube.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the details of your circuit you may be able to use one of these

http://www.linear.com/pc/productDetail.jsp?navId=H0,C1,C1003,C1142,C1029,P38400